# Changing top navigation behavior for an intra

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I need to change top global navigation behavior from hover to onclick. The navigation pull down menu should open after a click on Level 1 item. To close the open menu I need to click somewhere outside this menu. How can I do that?

Comment: try this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/04/rotating-banner-in-sharepoint-2013-using-content-search-webpart.html) article:

About your requirement, you can use the Script Edit web part to add the Front-end code in the SharePoint site.

In this article, it offers a variety of menu dropdown styles, you can choose the appropriate code according to your requirement.